# add popups window with link

Tags: navigation

I want to build popups in Drupal 8. This is the code I am using.

```
$attr = array(
 'attributes' => [
   'class' => ['use-ajax'],
   'data-dialog-type' => 'modal',
   'data-dialog-options' => Json::encode([
     'width' => 700,
   ]),
 ]
);
$url = Url::fromRoute('resume.grade_detail', ['uid' => $id, 'courseid' => $courseid]);
$internal_link = \Drupal::l($average, $url, $attr);

return array('#markup => $internal_link);
```

In the rendered output, i don't find the CSS classes I added; as result, the popup doesn't work.

I need help.

Answer (score 3):

The markup element strips some HTML tags from the output. It is much better to just use the following code.

```
$attr = [
 'attributes' => [
   'class' => ['use-ajax'],
   'data-dialog-type' => 'modal',
   'data-dialog-options' => Json::encode([
     'width' => 700,
   ]),
 ]
];
$link = Link::createFromRoute($average, 'resume.grade_detail', ['uid' => $id, 'courseid' => $courseid], $attr);

return $link->toRenderable();
```

Comment: ok, thanks. but i get error like below. 

Fatal error: Method Drupal\Core\Template\Attribute::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Error: Call to undefined method Drupal\Core\Url::render().

Comment: fix it like this, $link = $link->toRenderable(); return render($link); that works now, thanks.

Comment: I don't know the context for your question, but it is not recommended to render render-elements manually. I.E> you should let the twig template engine render them.